# Creating a FAT32 SD card image (.img) out of a directory using command-line tools

Tags: command-line, bash, automation, sd-card, disk-image

I'm writing a program which is meant to be loaded and run exclusively from a FAT32 SD card. I need to create an SD card image for distribution as well as for testing the storage and retrieval of files through this program (also exclusively on the SD card).

I want to use a BASH script to automate the creation of this IMG file which contains the binaries of my program. What command line program can I use to achieve this and how do I use it?

Comment: Bash is a CLI shell.  Why wouldn't you use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below would create the disk image file `myimage.img`, then copy the contents of the Desktop folder `MyFolder` to a FAT32 formatted volume stored in this disk image.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create the empty disk image file,
dd if=/dev/zero of=myimage.img bs=1m count=100
# Assign a /dev entry to the disk image file,
devEntry="$(hdiutil attach -nomount myimage.img)"
# Show ouput from hdiutil.
echo "$devEntry"
# Remove whitespace from variable devEntry.
devEntry="$(echo $devEntry)"
# Create a MBR partition table and mount the newly created FAT32 volume.
diskutil erasedisk fat32 MYSD mbr "$devEntry"
# Copy files from the folder to FAT32 volume.
cp -R ~/Desktop/MyFolder/ /Volumes/MYSD
# Remove all ._* files.
dot_clean /Volumes/MYSD
# Eject the disk image.
hdiutil detach "$devEntry"
```

A few comments are given below.

- The size of the disk image is 100 MiB. You can change this by editing `count=100`.
- The sector size of the SD card is assumed to be 512 bytes.
- You can use the `dd` command to transfer the image to a SD card. The capacity of the SD card must be at least that of the disk image file size.
- The use of `dot_clean` is optional.
- If the SD card does not require a partition table, then you can replace the command `diskutil erasedisk fat32 MYSD mbr "$devEntry"` with the command given below.

  ```
  diskutil erasevolume fat32 MYSD "$devEntry"
  ```

Comment: This worked! It generated the IMG file I wanted. I also checked the contents of the file and it wasn't full of zeroes either. I then mounted it in an emulator and ran my program and it appears to work fine.

Comment: By the way: when I didn't specify `mbr` in `diskutil`, it defaulted to GPT (or at least, the text "UEFI" showed up in the hex editor when viewing the file.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `diskutil` command line tool to achieve what you want. It allows mounting a file as a sort of loopback device, and it is able to perform FAT32 formatting.

Comment: `diskutil` resulted in this weird error (exit code 22 during copy process if I remember) and I couldn't find anything about it online. I prefer David Anderson's `dd` solution.

Comment: Yes, dd is a fine program - here you just use it to create a file of a specific size filled with zeroes. You can basically use any program to create a file of a size you want, it doesn't have to be filled with zeroes.. so you could even just record screencast with Quicktime and use that as a starting point ;-)